# The derivative of a uniformly convex function is onto

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, convex-analysis

My question stems from Evans' PDE book (p.142 in 2nd ed). Given that $F:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Assume that $F$ is uniformly convex ($F'' \geq \theta > 0$ for some constant $\theta$). Evans mentions that $F^{\prime}$ is onto on (pg $144$).

I'm not seeing why must $F'$ is surjective. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: @NormalHuman, will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the mean value theorem, 
$$
F'(x)-F'(0) = F''(\xi)x,\quad \text{for some $\xi$ between $0$ and $x$}
$$
Since $F''(\xi)\ge \theta$, it follows that $F'(x)\to+\infty$ as $x\to+\infty$ and $F'(x)\to-\infty$ as $x\to-\infty$. Since $F'$ is also continuous, by the intermediate value theorem it attains all real values.

Comment: I totally forgot about the MVT. Much appreciated. I'll accept your answer in a bit as it won't let me accept it at the moment.